# spark streaming reducebywindow

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

i have a batch size = 20 seconds , in each rdd i have scores i need to sum all scores  every 20 seconds so i did this :

```
JavaDStream<Double> res = scoreC.map(r -> r._2);
res.reduceByWindow((x,y) -> x+y,Durations.seconds(600),Durations.seconds(20)).print()
```

the result is empty 
how can i get the sum of scores every 20 seconds including previous sum for, example :

```
t-1 = 0 
t = 0
t+20 = 0 + 0 + 1.5
t+40 = 0 + 0 + 1.5 + 2 
t+60 = 0 + 0 + 1.5 + 2 + .... 
...
t+600 = sum(all) from t=0 to t=600
```

Comment: That should do the trick. What is `res.print()` saying?  Is your base stream working?

Comment: when i set batch size = 5 seconds and  i do a reducebykeyandwindow(..,20seconds,20seconds) to calculate a score for tweets  and after that i need to sum all this scores every 20 seconds so i did reducebywindow(10min,20seconds) the result is empty , but when i changed the batch size to 20 seconds its worked

Comment: "i do a `reduceByKeyAndWindow(.., 20seconds,20seconds)` to calculate a score for tweets" << This will give you one score per 20-second window. Don't you want to score each tweet ? If so, why use `reduceByKeyAndWindow` in that scoring phase ?